# How to create a new empty Tree

Tags: rust

I have a `Tree` and I want to create a new empty tree. My first thought is:

```
struct Tree<T> {
    key: T,
    l: Option<Box<Tree<T>>>,
    r: Option<Box<Tree<T>>>,
}

impl<T: Ord> Tree<T> {
    /// Creates an empty tree
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Tree {
            key: None, // error of mismatch type
            l: None,
            r: None,
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error of `Error: mismatched types [E0308]`

Is it a problem of type `T` not matching type `None`?

Comment: `None` is **not** a type. It is a *value* of the type `Option`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
type Tree<T> = Option<Box<TreeNode<T>>>;

struct TreeNode<T> {
    key: T,
    l: Tree<T>,
    r: Tree<T>,
}
```

Now creating an empty `Tree` is easy (just `None`), as it is to bind two `Tree`s into a new bigger one.

If you don't like the `None`-as-empty or the box in the root tree, you could add a wrapper type instead of the alias `Tree`, but the main idea is the same: move the `Option` from the left/right branches into the node type.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you make your `Tree` an enum instead of a struct?

I'd create a binary `Tree` like this:

```
enum Tree<T> {
    Empty,
    Node {
        val: T,
        l: Box<Tree<T>>,
        r: Box<Tree<T>>,
    },
}
```

You could then implement it like this:

```
impl<T: Ord> Tree<T> {
    fn empty() -> Self {
        Tree::Empty
    }
    fn singleton(val: T) -> Self {
        Tree::Node {
            val: val,
            l: Box::new(Tree::Empty),
            r: Box::new(Tree::Empty),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `key: T` you are explicitly asking for a value of type `T`. What you gave in the initialization (`key: None`) is an `Option<U>`, you need to give it some value, for example by changing `new` to

```
pub fn new(t: T) -> Self {
    Tree {
        key: t,
        l: None,
        r: None,
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you also want the ability to sometimes have keys, and sometimes not, you can change the `key` field to type `Option<T>`